# Google SignIn - Android - screen freezes when clicking

Tags: android, google-signin

I'm using Google Sign-In in one of my apps. I  got the code from this link - https://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

I did everything perfectly but whenever I click on Sign-In, the app freezes and crashes eventually.

Can't seem to figure-out what I'm doing wrong.

**This is my log:**

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
                                        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:269)
                                            at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:4884)
                                            at com.miui.server.XSpaceManagerService.isPublicIntent(XSpaceManagerService.java:174)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.checkXSpaceControl(ActivityStackSupervisorInjector.java:56)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:897)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3478)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3465)
                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:140)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2245)
                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309) 
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
```

This is my **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.hitesh.google_login;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

    import java.nio.BufferUnderflowException;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        private SignInButton btnSignIn;
        private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
        private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
        private ImageView imgProfilePic;
        private TextView txtName, txtEmail;





        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
            btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
            btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
            llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
            imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
            txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

            btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();

            // Customizing G+ button
            btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
            btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());


     }



        private void signIn() {
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }


        private void signOut() {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            updateUI(false);
                        }
                    });
        }

        private void revokeAccess() {
            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(Status status) {
                            updateUI(false);
                        }
                    });
        }

        private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
                GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

                Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

                String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
    //            String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                String email = acct.getEmail();

              //  Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                //        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                txtName.setText(personName);
                txtEmail.setText(email);


                updateUI(true);
            } else {
                // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
                updateUI(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                    signIn();
                    break;

                case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                    signOut();
                    break;

                case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                    revokeAccess();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (opr.isDone()) {
                // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
                // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
                Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
                GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
                handleSignInResult(result);
            } else {
                // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
                // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
                // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
                showProgressDialog();
                opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                        handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
            // be available.
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
        }

        private void showProgressDialog() {
            if (mProgressDialog == null) {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            }

            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        private void hideProgressDialog() {
            if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                mProgressDialog.hide();
            }
        }

        private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else
                {
                btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post you codes and crash logs

Comment: do not copy paste from demo . understand what happen there . show logcat

Comment: Sure. I haven't generated one yet, but I'll generated one now and post here.

Comment: Without code or error log unable to find your problem dear. follow a right steps from this tutorial and check..of any problem then debug a code. and if any error arise then post here.

Comment: @shrddhapatel share your crash logs

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by generating signed apk instead of debugging directly from IDE

Comment: Previously i implemented the same, Check if user image is not available on the gmail then it getting Null on image. It can be one reason of crashing.

Comment: I also got this problem. Prefectly fine in Android OS 6.0 and higher, but freeze in Android OS 4.2 Jelly bean. have you fixed this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use my code .Its working code by reference the of same website.

build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.logingoogle"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    // glide is added to load the g+ profile image. Ignore if you want
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llProfile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imgProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
          />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_logout_from_google"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_revoke_access"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_revoke_access"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imgPP"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.admin.logingoogle;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic,imgPP;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        imgPP = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPP);
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Customizing G+ button
        btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();

            Uri personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl();
            String email = acct.getEmail();

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                     .load(personPhotoUrl)
                     .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                     .into(imgProfilePic);
//            if (personPhotoUrl != null) {
//                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(personPhotoUrl)
//                        .resize(100, 100)
//                        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
//                        .into(imgProfilePic);
//            }
           // imgPP.setImageURI(personPhotoUrl);

            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                signIn();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnSignOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnRevokeAccess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for me. but in some devices the app freezes.

Comment: Check the API version of the device and tell me. @shrddhapatel

Comment: xiaomi note 3 and api version is 22.(version 5.1.1)

Comment: but my project doesn't crash. its freezzes. it doesn't give any error..

Comment: Now i checked my code on Android 6.0 API 23 its working fine as API 19 @shrddhapatel

Answer (score 0):

You are calling and using signin code in the MainActivty UI Thread due to which your application thread goes in waiting state until it get response from google.

To resolve it write the signin code in the separate thread so that while application is requesting respose it dont put main UI thread in waiting state. Which will help in resolving the issue of freezing application. Thread Documentation can be seen here [Thread Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

use below code for Google Sign in it also works with your own custom button:

```
public class GoogleLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    if(checkPlayServices(this)) {
        buildGoogleApiClient(googleSignInOptions);
    }
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.CustomProgressDialog);
    LivepoolsUtils.showProgressDialog(this,progressDialog);
    if(Validator.isNotNull(mGoogleApiClient)) {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, Constants.RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

}


private void buildGoogleApiClient(GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions) {
    if(Validator.isNull(mGoogleApiClient)){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
                .build();
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static boolean checkPlayServices(Context context) {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog((GoogleLogin)context, resultCode, Constants.PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Toast.makeText(this,acct.getDisplayName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        email=acct.getEmail();


    }
    else
    {

      finish();
    }
}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```